# Unable to understand the code in the Append() in a C program

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to read a program that I came across online. I have been trying to read and understand the program, I have understood all the lines of code except the lines given below. I would be very grateful to you all if you all could help me understand those lines. The full code can be found at [this site](http://sourcecodesonline.blogspot.com/2010/09/10implementation-of-simple-text-editor.html)

```
    while(1)
  {
   c=getch();
   if(c==19)
    goto end3;
   if(c==13)
   {
    c='\n';
    printf("\n\t");
    fputc(c,fp1);
   }
   else
   {
    printf("%c",c);
    fputc(c,fp1);
   }
  }
```

Comment: Any line in particular?

Comment: You didn't understand the `if` or `while` statements?

Comment: @JonathanWood To be fair, the code is pretty shitty to put it mildly.

Comment: @JustSid May be. But OP says he understood rest of the code, just not this part!

Comment: @BlueMoon Point taken. Especially since the rest isn't any better.

Comment: I mean the if statement @JonathanWood. I dont know why and what the if statement has (c== 13) and (c==19). The program after appending text to the file needs to be saved pressing Ctrl+S key in the command prompt.Thank you for your response.

Comment: @user3638069 Edit your question to clarify, if you want to survive this question!

Comment: In this case (I'm going to assume a terminal program here), Ctrl + S will be character 19, which is the if(c == 19) bit. Character 13 is a line feed, i.e. enter.

Comment: The code shown above is a part of the Append() function for the simple text editor program. I understood the rest of the codes or the functions but not this one. I tried to find similar codes on the internet with some explanations but i found none. I am unable to understand  the if statement, to be precise if(c==13) and if (c==19) part. Hope it is a bit clearer @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: Although if it *is* a terminal program, many terminals will catch Ctrl+S and suspend, rather than giving you the behaviour you wanted.

Comment: @user3638069 I said: **Edit your question!** I didn't request your comments!

Comment: Thank you @slugonamission this solves my problem i guess. Thanks to others for their effort as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while(1)                  // Loop forever.
   {
   c=getch();             // read a character from stdin.
   if(c==19)              // If the character read is 'CTRL-S',
      goto end3;          //   jump to the 'end3' label.

   if(c==13)              // If the character read is '(Carriage) Return',
      {
      c='\n';             //    Set 'c' to be a C 'newline' character.
      printf("\n\t");     //    Write a 'newline' and a 'tab' character to stdout.
      fputc(c,fp1);       //    Write the value of 'c' to the fp1 stream.
      }
   else                   // If the character read is -not- '(Carriage) Return',
      {
      printf("%c",c);     //    Write the character to stdout.
      fputc(c,fp1);       //    Write the value to the fp1 stream.
      }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Appreciate it.@Mahonri

Answer (score -1):

Because this is some pretty ugly code, here's a much simpler re-write:

```
while(1)
{
    if((c=getch()) == 19)  // If Ctrl+S, end this While-Loop
    { 
        break; // Goto is EVIL!
    }

    fputc((c=='\r')? (puts("\n\t"), '\n') :      // Convert Return to \n, OR
                     (putchar(c),     c ), fp1); // Put out exactly the char that was input.
}
```

Comment: Completely avoiding `goto` can be uglier and more error-prone than using it wisely, though.

Comment: Completely disagree, @Chnossos.  Goto is NEVER called for in well designed code.

Comment: Uh ? There are cases like [releasing resources on error](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MEM12-C.+Consider+using+a+goto+chain+when+leaving+a+function+on+error+when+using+and+releasing+resources) that are better handled with some goto than without (and this is an example, real life code can be way more complicated/handle way more resources than that one).

Comment: This question that i have asked last year gives me this "

Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?

Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.
" every time I log into stackover flow, do I need to edit it even now?